# How to display output using Input tag?

Tags: javascript, calculator

i am new to javascript, now i am making calculator using javascript, how to display the text using both DIV and INPUT tags. I tried using div but it's not working. how to fix it.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Show what you have tried?

Comment: show us your existing broken code and we can have a go at helping you

Answer (score 3):

Use this for div

```
document.getElementById('divid').text="put your text"
```

for input field

```
document.getElementById('inputid').value="put your text"
```

Hope this helps...